# Plugins on nodejs across multiple apps , what package to use? (With wordpress in mind)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, twitter-bootstrap, express

I am concurrently writing a few apps which use "plugins" that can be run separately and independently on a nodejs/mongo platform. These apps use independent models for mongo collections, routes and views (MVC).

My question: what package should I use to manage this Github/npm or other ?

More info : Ideally I would like to edit one plugin and through "github/npm " they would all be modified. What is suggested to manage this? Github seems limited with this and would like to make sure that npm is the right choice before modifying code to make this work.

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Aftere some playing around , the NPM package manager seems best ,

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////
////       FRATERNATE NPM MODULE          //// 
/////////////////////////////////////////////
var fraternate = require("fraternate");
app.use('/', fraternate);
```